# Wordpress Shortcode array issue

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

This is how to shortcode looks `[posts3col ids="249, 318, 93" category="Events"]`

And this is some of the code behind it, where I have the problem:

```
add_shortcode('posts3col', 'posts_func');

function posts_func($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'ids'=> '',
        'category' => ''        
    ), $atts));

    $options=array(
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'category_name' => $category,
            'post__in' => array($ids)
            );
    ob_start(); 
    // run the loop based on the query
    $query = new WP_Query( $options ); .....
```

The problem I have is with 'post__in', I don't know how to give it the ids. 
If I write the ids manually in the code like this:

```
'post__in' => array(249, 318, 93)
```

it works, but obviously I need to pull the ids from the shortcode I can't insert them manually.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `var_dump($ids)` ?

Comment: +1 for including code, it makes life a whole lot easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to convert string to array.

```
$options=array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'category_name' => $category,
        'post__in' => explode(",", $ids);
      );
```